# Is there a function to eliminate repetitive factors?

Tags: prime-factorization

Say I have a number, like 60.
Which has a prime factorization of $$[2,2,3,5]$$
What function would take in 60 and remove redundant factors? In this case, it should return 30

Edit: I did some more research, and the term I'm wording in looking for is reducing a number to its distinct factors

Comment: Are you referring to a script for programming?

Comment: @mrnovice no I mean mathematical notation or a pre established function

Comment: Can we assume that the prime factorisation of the input is known?

Comment: @mrnovice yeah, I thought of it like dividing the number by each factor raised to its multiplicity minus one. So 4 would become 2, 12 would be 6

Comment: One could also think of it as finding the largest square-free divisor of your number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lets define the following function:

Given $x = \prod_{i=1}^{n}p_{i}^{a_{i}}$ i.e. the prime factorisation of $x$

$f(x):= \prod_{i=1}^{n}p_{i}$

Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: Yes but I want it to reduce factors to plus or minus 1 multiplicity

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean, doesn't this function achieve that?

Comment: possibly, I must admit I'm not totally mathematically literate and I don't quite understand your notation

Comment: It essentially means, that we are given $x$ in the form of the product of its prime factors, so then we define $f(x)$ as the the product of the prime factors of $x$, but each with exponent $1$ as required. The $\prod_{i=1}^{n}$ symbol means the product from $i=1$ to $n$

Comment: I made an edit that has more meaning

Comment: as far as I can see, my function should still fit your purpose.

Answer (score 1):

In the context of ring theory, you can think of the number $n$ as the ideal $(n)$ in the ring $\mathbb{Z}$. The object you're looking for is called the [radical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_of_an_ideal) of the ideal.

Comment: I want it to reduce numbers so that each factor has minimal multiplicity

Comment: That's what the radical does.

Comment: I made an edit for clarity